# 3 controllers on the same page showing different results for $state.is()

Tags: angularjs

First of all, apologies I don't have an example to show. The current situation is I am using UI Router and I have 3 views with a different controller each on the same page with the state name 'result'. i.e. for the head, content and sidebar.

However, only 1 of the controllers (content) return `true` when I call for `$state.is('result')`. I've also tried `$state.includes('result')`.

When I log the `$state` only, all 3's state object shows the same correct `\result` in `$state.current.name`, however, if I try to log `$state.current` directly, the `name` becomes blank for 2 of them.

I've tried swapping the order of the views, but only content is returning `true`.

I read the doc many times, but I can't find the reason why. Please help!

```
.state('result', {
    url: '/result',
    views: {
        'headView' : {
            templateUrl: 'modules/core/templates/head.html'
        },
        'contentView' : {
            templateUrl: 'modules/core/templates/content.html'
        },                      
        'sidebarView' : {
            templateUrl: 'modules/core/templates/sidebar.html'
        },
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Place your controllers in your state view definitions where your `templateUrl`s are defined.

E.G.

**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/qnJXHKO7NQCq3NYsHbBW?p=preview)**

```
.state('result', {
    url: '/result',
    views: {
        'headView' : {
            templateUrl: 'modules/core/templates/head.html',
            controller: 'HeadViewController',
        },
        'contentView' : {
            templateUrl: 'modules/core/templates/content.html',
            controller: 'ContentViewController'
        },                      
        'sidebarView' : {
            templateUrl: 'modules/core/templates/sidebar.html',
            controller: 'SidebarViewController'
        },
    }
})
```